# Cannot extract text from Element Jsoup

Tags: java, jsoup, element

Why can I not get the text from this element?

```
Elements el = doc.select("#Core_UI_AutogeneratedID_0 > fieldset:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(23)");
for (Element e : el) {
      System.out.println(e.text());
}
```

I am connecting to the website fine, it's this line that's the issue

```
Elements el = doc.select("#Core_UI_AutogeneratedID_0 > fieldset:nth-child(1) > p:nth-child(23)");
```

How would I print an Element?

HTML format:

```
<div class="Content">
<fieldset class="TableLike FixedLabelSmall Narrow">

    <label>Age:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="9 d 21 h ">9 d 21 h </p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

    <label>Created:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="06/13/2015 11:10">06/13/2015 11:10</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>


    <label>State:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="closed successful">closed successful</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

    <label>Locked:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="unlock">unlock</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

    <label>Priority:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="3 normal">3 normal</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

    <label>Queue:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="Sydney">Sydney </p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

    <label>Service:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="SUV">SUV</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>
    <label>Service Level Agreement:</label>
    <p class="Value" title="**I WANT THIS TEXT**">Sydney SLA</p>
    <div class="Clear"></div>

</fieldset>
```

Comment: what is the html structure of this  part that you are trying to select ??

Comment: that's fine but can you give the link of the page or the entire source code .post entire HTML structure somewhere like pastebin.com then add link to your question because can't see Core_UI_AutogeneratedID_0

Comment: I cannot show you the whole website as it is a private website but could you show me with this website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sample_(statistics)
with this element #toc > ul > li.toclevel-1.tocsection-2 > a > span.toctext

to extract this text 2 Mathematical description of random sample

Comment: with your given example page wiki your selectors are fine and it will get the text "Mathematical description of random sample" .didn't you able to get it using jsoup ??and try this site this will help to find is your selectors are ok for ur private website. http://try.jsoup.org/

Comment: That site is very good thanks